# dial tcp 172.17.0.2:26657: connect: connection refused

Tags: docker, connection, tendermint

I have been trying to use tm-monitor to do a load-test on tendermint network. I gave the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm -v "/tmp:/tendermint" tendermint/tendermint init
docker run -it --rm -v "/tmp:/tendermint" -p "26657:26657" --name=tm tendermint/tendermint node --proxy_app=kvstore
docker run -it --rm -p "26670:26670" --link=tm tendermint/monitor tm:26657
```

The third command however gives me the error:

```
dial tcp 172.17.0.2:26657: connect: connection refused
```

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, the RPC interface is set to `localhost (127.0.0.1)`. You may want to listen for RPC on any interface (i.e. `0.0.0.0`).

To check on which interface tendermint is listening on, run:

```
netstat -tlnp | grep tendermint
```

You will get something like:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:26657         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      94133/tendermint
```

Change the interface in `config.toml`. Search for `laddr` and replace `127.0.0.1` with `0.0.0.0` or with the specific address you want (e.g. `172.17.0.2`). Restart tendermint and check the with netstat again. You should get:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::26657                :::*                    LISTEN      99287/tendermint
```

Comment: The question is no more valid as the authors have deprecated Tm-monitor.